# Can I subpeona a bank to get contact information of bank account holders who defrauded me?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, fraud, subpoena

I have been a victim of online fraud. A large amount of money flowed from my account to various (around 10) Bank of America/PayPal accounts in the US. I have filed a police report. The police report mentions the account holders names with account numbers redacted.

I have found two of the perpetrators and have filed a civil lawsuit against them to recover whatever money I can. But I am having a hard time figuring out the contact information of the rest of the perpetrators. Since I have a police report and my account shows the bank transfers, can I issue a subpoena to the bank via the court to give me the contact information of the perpetrators?

Comment: Be aware that theres a good likelihood that the other accounts are also stolen or used without the owners knowledge or permission - routing through several stolen accounts is a common approach to money laundering.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this is allowed under the civil procedure rules of most U.S. jurisdictions. The fact that there is a live suit against some named defendants helps a great deal. The process for doing so isn't necessarily uniform, however, in every U.S. state.

Comment: Thank you. To issue a subpeona to access their bank info, I will need to serve the other party (that I am trying to access their bank info) . I guess this is part of the sub peona process. But since I don't have their address, I cannot serve them. So it's a chicken and egg situation. Any help? Thank you.

Comment: @mildman If you can use the pre-existing case, you can serve on the last known address by mail. If you need to start a new case, you can hire a skip-trace firm to find their address. Generally there must be some way to communicate if there is an action in which the funds are being garnished and one could get a judge to authorize substituted service in that case or otherwise issues orders in that case so that you don't need to start a new case.